# How can I display dBi signal strength instead of graphical bars in B315s or any other 4G router?

Tags: networking, signals, dbi, 4g, huawei-mobile-services

I got an antenna for my 4G router (Huawei B315s), I want to start aligning and directing this thing to the signal source, but the signal bars are not accurate enough.

Is the there any way to get it to display the signal in dBi?

I have Kali and windows 10. If there is any software on one of them please lead me to it.

Answer (score 4):

Many Huawei routers expose dBm values via an API, which you can access simply with a web browser. On my B310s pointing browser to

http://192.168.64.1/api/device/signal

displays, as an example

-7dB -89dBm -71dBm 12dB 7

the 2nd one is rsrp.

I found I have to open the normal router home page first to make this work.

There's a python package if you want to do fancy stuff like send SMS's
https://pypi.org/project/huawei-lte-api/

Update: I've since found some software that makes this a lot more user friendly - for Android: HuaCtrl; for Windows: LTEInspecteur.

Comment: Brilliant! I can confirm that this works with a B315 s. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a Windows Utility that can connect to Huawei HiLink devices call [Huawei Toolbox](http://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php/798330-Toolbox-for-new-Huawei-HiLink-devices-(E5186-B315s)). Use the dBm value for RSSI and RSRP as the signal strength indicators for each antenna.